# Angular2 error: Imports needed to create a search bar

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to create a website that's basically a clone of ebay with a search bar but I get errors when trying to import the right files.

Here's a screenshot of what the error looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seqgc.png)

Here is a link to the plunker (full project):

```
 plnkr.co/edit/1lcI4dURHwA8D9IQtqSf?p=info
```

Here is a link to the dropbox version of the full project (note this does not include the nodes_modules folder):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/quuh3s27pvv5jl6/ImportProjectErrors.zip?dl=0

The code of the file I'm trying to change (youtubesearchapp.ts):

```
import {boostrap,
    View,
 ON_PUSH} 
 from 'angular2/core';
import {
  bind,
  Component,
  Injectable,
} from 'angular2/core';
import{
  CORE_DIRECTIVES,
} from 'angular2/common'


import { ChangeDetectionStrategy} from 'angular2/core';
import {
  Http, HTTP_BINDINGS
} from 'angular2/http'
import {
  FormBuilder, 
  Validators,
  FORM_BINDINGS,
  FORM_DIRECTIVES
} from 'angular2/common';
```

Screenshot of other file's import error:

dropbox.com/s/i12eg8za9kmeii7/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-10%20at%203.37.59%20PM.png?dl=0

Code of other file I'm trying to change (wikipedia.service.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/common';



import { Jsonp, URLSearchParams } from 'angular2/http';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which version of angular 2 are you using? if you are using RC 0 or RC 1. Imports have changed:

```
To import various symbols please adjust the paths in the following way:

angular2/core -> @angular/core
angular2/compiler -> @angular/compiler
angular2/common -> @angular/common
angular2/platform/browser -> @angular/platform-browser (applications with precompiled templates) + @angular/platform-browser-dynamic (applications that compile templates on the fly)
angular2/platform/server -> @angular/platform-server
angular2/testing -> @angular/core/testing (it/describe/..) + @angular/compiler/testing (TestComponentBuilder) + @angular/platform-browser/testing
angular2/upgrade -> @angular/upgrade
angular2/http -> @angular/http
angular2/router -> @angular/router-deprecated (snapshot of the component router from beta.17 for backwards compatibility)
new package: @angular/router - component router with several breaking changes
```

source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I don't know how to check which version I'm using to be honest

Comment: There are 2 ways to do it: 1. Goto node_modules > angular2> package.json and check the version there or 2. go to package.json file in your project, find the property dependencies in there and Check the version of angular2. I prefer the first method, since the package.json can use version indicators like >, ~, ^ etc, so it might not always give you the exact version number.

Comment: I changed it but for some reason I still get the same error:

Here is my package.json file https://www.dropbox.com/s/zephu0kxy2ti2rc/package.json?dl=0

Comment: 1.0.0 I think? At least it said '1.0.0' next to the "version:" in the package.json file other than that I don't know

Comment: Just to make sure you are using latest angular.  "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.15"
replace this by
"angular2": "^2.0.0-rc.1" in your package.json to get latest Angular version. try "npm install"

Comment: caution: there you have to change your imports to use the latest "@" and start using providers etc.

Comment: Okay I changed it but it might be a different error on your machine than mine, here's the link to it https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvtrxacig5p6yeu/ImportsError.zip?dl=0
For some reason I still get the same error though I'd like to know if you get it too or it's just my machine that's incorrect

Comment: sweve I am on mobile, I cant unzip your file. can you post them without zipping? just try clearing your node modules and repopulating them using "npm install"